# How to make the button more reactive

Tags: javascript, performance, button, colors, reactive

If I click the button too fast, then it doesn't execute as if it didn't register the click. Is there any way I can make this simple code react better? Or is this pretty much the extent of it?
any advice would be helpful to help me in future mini-projects such as this.

```js
// function named change_color which contains color array and random selection
function change_Color(){
    // creating color variable equal to the color array
    var color = ["blue", "red", "green", "yellow"];
    // created random variable targeting the color variable saying to choose
    // a random color from the array
    var random = color[Math.floor(Math.random()*color.length)];
    // targets the the div element with id wrapper, telling it to use the
    // random variable
    document.getElementById("wrapper").style.backgroundColor = random;
}
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: skyblue;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    button {
        padding: 10px;
        background: orange;
        color: white;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 10px;
        font-size: 2rem;
        transition: .5s ease;

        &:hover {
            box-shadow: 0 4px 3px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        &:focus {
            outline: 0;
            color: skyblue;
        }
    }
    

}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <button onclick="change_Color()">Click me!</button>
    </div>
    <script src="JS/style.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: You could also get the exact same color multiple times in a row (chance 1/4), which makes it seem like the event didn't register. Could that be the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're at the mercy of the hardware layer at this point, but you could move any code that doesn't need to be in the function out of the function so there is less to process. Again though, you may not see any improvement because a `click` triggers operations that are outside of the JavaScript runtime's boundaries and the browser's code, which in turn invokes operating system code, runs next.

```js
// The following two lines don't need to be invoked 
// over and over and could potentially speed things
// up by not being in the function.
var color = ["blue", "red", "green", "yellow"];
let wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper");

// function named change_color which contains color array and random selection
function change_Color(){
    // There's no reason for a variable if you only use its value once:
    wrapper.style.backgroundColor = color[Math.floor(Math.random()*color.length)];
}
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: skyblue;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    button {
        padding: 10px;
        background: orange;
        color: white;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 10px;
        font-size: 2rem;
        transition: .5s ease;

        &:hover {
            box-shadow: 0 4px 3px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        &:focus {
            outline: 0;
            color: skyblue;
        }
    }
    

}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <button onclick="change_Color()">Click me!</button>
    </div>
    <script src="JS/style.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: just to clarify because I am new to this. You can set the color to a global and it will still work with the function, and by setting the random method to the wrapper.style will reduce code and possibly execution time?

Comment: @A.D.Schmidt Since your color array doesn't change, there's no reason to re-declare the Array object and re-populate it upon each click of the button. Similarly, there's no need to search through the document to find the wrapper each time you click the button, so just find it once and then use that reference as often as you like. Lastly, a variable is for temporarily holding information. If you are only going to use that information one time, you don't really need to set up a place to hold it. With all of that said, I don't think you'd actually see much improvement because...

Comment: @A.D.Schmidt ... as I mentioned in my answer, there are aspects of what you are doing that is outside of your or JavaScript's control.